# Should gRPC server and client be in the same repository?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, grpc-go

I am playing around with a gRPC server using Go,
I understand that one of the benefits of gRPC/Protobuf is that you can use it to create a client library easily by using the same messages/service API that are being used in the server code.

If I am implementing a client library for my service, it obviously needs to import the service code and API, so I would eventually have a service, a server, and a client components. In production grade code - should all of these components exist in the same repository and be separated only by the go packages? Should the service be its own repository and serve as a dependency to anyone wished to implement server/client libraries for the service?

Comment: Proper capitalization is "gRPC", not "GrPC"

Answer (score 1):

> should all of these components exist in the same repository and be
>   separated only by the go packages?

The various gRPC components do not need to all live in the same repo.

> Should the service be its own repository and serve as a dependency to
>   anyone wished to implement server/client libraries for the service?

I use the following repo organization:

- myapp-proto (common repo; git tagged and used by both client and
  server)
- myapp-client
- myapp-service1
- myapp-service2
- myapp-service3

For example, several gRPC services which pull data from various datasources (REST APIs, MySQL, LDAP etc.) - each of these server gRPC services live in their own repos. There is a single gRPC client package that also lives in it's own repo. And to keep change-control sane, the common `proto` definitions (and generated go code) lives in a separate single repo.

The above setup leverages [git version tagging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) and [go modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) to ensure the client and all the servers are using the compatible versions of the gRPC messages/services. Adding methods/fields to the gRPC `proto` can be done independent of the client/server pieces - and phased in when mature.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience what has worked best is to keep the proto definition and generated files with the server. I typically put them in `{SERVER}/pkg/grpc` and then import them in client `{CLIENT}/internal/services/{SERVER}/grpc` or something similar depending on your project structure.